# Proxy_pass with Nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, proxypass

I have a simple task with nginx, but I cannot work it out:

I have a domain `example.com`, which points to a local server `192.168.1.150`, which runs nginx in docker.

But I have another container, "myapp" running on port 8080, and I want to pass this location - from "https://192.168.1.150/myapp" and "https://example.com/myapp" to "http://192.168.1.150:8080", which is http only, and I want to have a secure connection through nginx.

**The Problem to solve**

At the moment if I request `https://192.168.1.150/myapp` it navigates to `https://192.168.1.150/login` but the target should be `https://192.168.1.150/myapp/login`. Although URL "changes" successfully, nginx responds HTTP 404;

See my location settings in nginx.conf:

```
location /myapp {
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.150:8080;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

**SSL**

Just a side note: I already set SSL up with redirecting from HTTP, tested with a simple location "/test", which returns plain text "OK", looks fine.

If this is cannot be solved like that, it is also OK for me to use it with another server and listen to another port than 443. (tried, same result)

Any help will be appriciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you are redirected? Then the app itself incorrectly redirects the user to /login instead of /myapp/login.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had to rewrite the request_uri as follows: `rewrite ^/myapp(.*) $1? break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question: I had to rewrite the uri to redirect correctly. I did not had the proper words to find the info on the net, but keywords like "preserve" helped to find examples.

The solution was to use the rewrite module of nginx and write a replacement for the 'myapp' section: `rewrite ^/myapp(.*) $1? break;`.

More info on [ngx_http_rewrite_module.html](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and search for 'replacement'.

So at the moment my working config with a simple Python http.server:

```
location /myapp/ {
    rewrite ^/myapp(.*) $1? break;
    proxy_pass          http://myapp$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host$request_uri;
    proxy_cache_bypa    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_f>
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Other redirections to web applications and servers do not work, but my question is resolved.

I also had problems without trailing slash like `example.com/myapp`, nginx dropped HTTP 500, which I overcame with this:

```
location ~ ^/myapp$ {
    return 301 $request_uri/;
}
```

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe this is what you need:

proxy_pass http://myapp;

Comment: For that I should define ```upstream myapp { server 192.168.1.150:8080 }``` right?
Same behavior.

Comment: No in your Code try http://myapp instead of http://192.168.1.150:8080

Comment: Did not work.
What I needed to use `rewrite ^/myapp(.*) /$1/$2 break;` but it is not OK for static files or complex applications. Just tested with simple http.server with python so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).